# Ошибка при попытке запустить тесты

Tags: java, android

Пытался запустить тесты по статье с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/post/255763/, но выводится непонятная ошибка.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugAndroidTest'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.khannanovayrat.cucumberespresso"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner 'ru.khannanovayrat.cucumberespresso.tests.CucuRunner'
        testHandleProfiling true
        testFunctionalTest true
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

    androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso-support-v4:1.1-r3')
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.1.8'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.1.8'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3'
    androidTestCompile ('info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.2')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

    androidTestCompile ('info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.1.8')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
                exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-integration'
                exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-library'
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько предположений по поводу данной ошибки:

1. В проекте содержатся классы с **дублирующимися** именами. [Прицедент №1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30717810/4728929)
2. В проекте превышен так называемый лимит **65К методов**. Возможно, подключение дублирующихся библиотек. [Прецедент №2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31297367/4728929)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно был конфликт библиотек